# Calculating differences between two rows for access sql query

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a query with a new column containing differences between row n and row n+1 for column X from Table 1.

---

Table 1

Sample_ID: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

X: 42060, 42069, 42069, 42111, 42132

---

Query 1 (ideal result)

Sample_ID: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Diff: 0, 9, 0, 42, 21

---

I used the following sql.

```
SELECT [Table1].Sample_ID,[Table1].X - Prev.X AS Diff
FROM [Table1] INNER JOIN [Table1] AS Prev
ON [Table1].Sample_ID -1 = Prev.Sample_ID
WHERE [Table1].Sample_ID > 1
```

However, it omits the first row; thus, instead of getting a result presented above as Query 1, I get the following.

---

Results

Sample_ID: 2, 3, 4, 5

Diff: 9, 0, 42, 21

---

How can I retain the first row (Sample_ID=1) as 0 value?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT [Table1].Sample_ID,[Table1].X - Prev.X AS Diff
  FROM [Table1] 
       INNER JOIN [Table1] AS Prev ON [Table1].Sample_ID -1 = Prev.Sample_ID
 WHERE [Table1].Sample_ID >= 1
```

which will pick up all rows which have a `SampleID` **greater than or equal to 1**, or

```
SELECT [Table1].Sample_ID,[Table1].X - Prev.X AS Diff
  FROM [Table1] 
       INNER JOIN [Table1] AS Prev ON [Table1].Sample_ID -1 = Prev.Sample_ID
 WHERE [Table1].Sample_ID IS NOT NULL
```

which will pick up all rows which **have** a `SampleID`

Answer (score -1):

Your WHERE clause states Sample_ID > 1 therefore it won't ever select the first row.

Two approaches are to change it to WHERE Sample_ID >= 1 or use a UNION query.

```
SELECT [Table1].Sample_ID,[Table1].X AS Diff WHERE Sample_ID = 1
UNION
SELECT [Table1].Sample_ID,[Table1].X - Prev.X AS Diff
  FROM [Table1] 
       INNER JOIN [Table1] AS Prev ON [Table1].Sample_ID -1 = Prev.Sample_ID
 WHERE [Table1].Sample_ID >= 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  UNION worked perfectly with a minor modification.  I just had to add FROM before WHERE in the first part of the union.  Thanks again.